# Why are both the text widgets not in the same line inside my table row in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to `Flutter`. I am trying to create a table which has two columns. In the first column, there should be a `text` and in the second one, there should be a `dropdown`. This is my code:

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.orange.shade400,
    border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.black, // Set border color
        width: 1.0),   // Set border width
  ),
  child:Table(
     border: TableBorder.all(
       color: Colors.black,
       style: BorderStyle.solid,
       width: 2),
     children: [
        TableRow( children: [
           Column(children:const [Text('Bill Type',style:TextStyle(fontSize: 16))]),
           Column(children:[DropdownButton<String>(
             key:bt,
             value: str,
             icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
             iconSize: 16,
             style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16,),
             onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  str = newValue!;
                });
             },
             items: <String>['AC', 'Electric current', 'Electric Arrear']
               .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                     value: value,
                     child: Center(
                        child:Text(value,textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                     ),
                  );
               }).toList(),
          )]),
        ]),
     ],
  ),
)
```

---

[This is the screenshot of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9CoL.png)

As you can see in the screenshot, the `text` in the left column and the `dropdown` in the right column are not in the same line. Both of them should be in the center of their respective columns.

Also, the selected `value` of the dropdown is not aligned in the center. How do I resolve these issues? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `defaultVerticalAlignment` property in the `Table` widget to `TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle` in order to center the cells' contents vertically. As for centering the **value** of the `DropDownButton` just set the `alignment` property to `Alignment.center`.